# Changing value of my hidden field with Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, html, razor

I'm having a hard time understanding this code that I was given to work on as I am a newbie at Javascript/HTML/C# Razor

Currently I have the following

```
<li class="control-group">
        <label for="autoReload" class="control-label">Auto Reload</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="btn-group radioButtons radioToggleCollapse" data-toggle-id="#autoReloadExtra" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
                <button type="button" data-value="no" class="btn active">No</button>
                <button type="button" data-value="yes" class="btn">Yes</button>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" class="radioHidden" value="'$'+@(Model.IsAutoReload ? "True" : "False")" id="autoReload" name="IsAutoReload">
        </div>
</li>
```

What I'm looking to do is when I click the button No, change the value in that text box to False, or if I click true then I want that value to be changed to true

I have found the following Javascript,

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#autoReload").on('change',function(){
                if ($(this).val() == 'yes') {
                    $(".saveCardSwitch button[data-value='true']").trigger('click');
                    $(".saveCardSwitch button").each(function(){
                        $(this).addClass('disabled').prop('disabled',true);
                    });
                }
                if ($(this).val() == 'no') {
                    $(".saveCardSwitch button").each(function(){
                        $(this).removeClass('disabled').prop('disabled',false);
                    });
                }
            });

        });
   </script>
```

Now I've tried switching the actual data-values on my buttons to true/false, but when I do that the hidden message that I have open doesnt show anymore so I'm kind of stuck at this point. I'd also like to clarify, when I call @(Model.IsReload ? "True" : "False" that passes the value back to my controller in the post method right?

Comment: which one isnt relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Jquery, You can do it the following way:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
   $('.radioHidden').val($(this).attr('data-value') === 'yes');
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LnDWN/1/)**

Comment: Jquery is a javascript Library, but yes. $ refers to the jquery namespace (unless you have overwritten that with something else ;) )

Comment: Ah I see, and thanks this is partially what I wanted however, I dont understand how this changed the value to true. Also, I wanted to use this also for when I click no to show false but Im not sure if this will mess it up. Lastly, I'd still like to pass in the value of True or False to Model.IsAutoReload still, does this occur?

Comment: $(this).attr('data-value') === 'yes' - This piece of code valides if what you clicked on's data-value is equal to yes (returns a bool). The $('.radioHidden').val() sets the radioHidden's value to this bool. You can inspect the html on your page to see it change as you click yes and no. You can also try console logging $(this).attr('data-value') === 'yes' (as done in the fiddle)

Comment: Hey Xeano, now whenever I click a button on the same page, I think this has to deal with using the $('btn').click function part, 
it will change to false, i've tried changing the class in both the button to btn2 as well as in the jquery function, but it then returns me a value of yes and no... any ideas?

Comment: I think radioBtn would be a more fitting name. Every element on your page which has the class btn will react to the earlier click event. It sounds like you're doing it right, but I wonder why it returns you a yes/no string value. Here is a version where I use the class radioBtn http://jsfiddle.net/LnDWN/4/

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand all you need is a function to set a value on a specific element. You can do that with the following code

```
<li class="control-group">
<label for="autoReload" class="control-label">Auto Reload</label>
<div class="controls">
    <div class="btn-group radioButtons radioToggleCollapse" data-toggle-id="#autoReloadExtra" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
        <button type="button" data-value="no" onclick="setValue(false, 'autoReload');" class="btn active">No</button>
        <button type="button" data-value="yes" onclick="setValue(true, 'autoReload');" class="btn">Yes</button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="radioHidden" value="" id="autoReload" name="IsAutoReload">
</div>
```

and your function setValue can be something like:

```
var setValue = function(value, id)
{
    var domEl = document.getElementById(id);
    domEl.value = value;
}
```

Comment: hey pavel, I need to pass this true/false value into the back into the model as Model.IsAutoReload, how can I do this with your implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to have any events bound to the buttons that you want to use to toggle that is the first thing you need, an onclick event you can do this

```
<button type="button" data-value="no" onclick="updateHidden(this.dataset.value)" class="btn active">No</button>
<button type="button" data-value="yes" onclick="updateHidden(this.dataset.value)" class="btn">Yes</button>
```

then the code to update the hidden input is

```
function updateHidden(value){
value = value==="yes"?"TRUE":"FALSE";
document.getElementById("autoReload").value = value;
}
```

Comment: Is Model a javascript object? Or is on the php side of your webpage?

Comment: @Model.IsAutoReload is a Razor reference to my controller

Comment: Razor is server-side no? I think you will need to pass the information back the your server to put it in the Model like you want it

Comment: Your current Razor reference is only grabbing currently stored information from your model and will not update the model in return as Razor is interpreted before it is sent to the client side